# Akka message undelivered

Tags: scala, akka

I've a `PropertiesStore` actor that holds a `mutable.Buffer` of runtime configuration that's manipulated through a rest API. You read and write from said store using these objects:

`Read(None, Property(key ="MyConfigKey", value = None))`

to which the store responds with the `Property` and its value.

In order to ease the locating of this store, I have another actor (a cameo) that I create on the fly:

```
object PropertyLookup {
  def apply(propertyKey: String, target: Option[ActorRef]): Props = {
    Props(new PropertyLookup(propertyKey, target))
  }
}

class PropertyLookup(key: String, target: Option[ActorRef]) extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  val PropertiesStore = "/user/Master/DataStore/PropertiesStore"
  val propertiesActor = context.actorSelection(PropertiesStore)

  def receive: Actor.Receive = {
    case _=>
      log.info(s"Looking up ${key} via ${propertiesActor}")
      propertiesActor.tell(Read(None, Property(key, None)), target.getOrElse(sender()))
      log.info(s"Sent property lookup to PropertiesStore: ${key}")
//      context.stop(self)
  }
}
```

Which enables me to keep the "locating" of said actor (i.e. via its path) in one place, avoiding too much rework if it's moved. This `PropertyLookup` has an optional target actor that the `PropertiesStore` will send the result to once the lookup is performed. I use all this like so in another actor to get a config value before I do some work:

```
  context.actorOf(PropertyLookup(PropertyKeys.SpreadsheetURL, None), s"PropertiesLookup_${self.path.name}") ! None
```

but when I do so, I get the following warning:

> Message [domain.Read] from
>   Actor[akka://NN/user/$a/Master/DataStore/PlayerStore#-1100303450] to
>   Actor[akka://NN/user/Master/DataStore/PropertiesStore] was not
>   delivered. [2] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned
>   off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters'
>   and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'

and I never receive my Property instance in the callee. The cameo (instance of `PropertyLookup`) does do its stuff and log, so I know that part is working.

What's happening? Is my cameo all wrong? Any better ways to do this? How do I understand what's happening around this warning>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your code and log outputs up to date?
First you gave definition of Read as

```
Read(Property(key ="MyConfigKey", value = None))
```

but then you are using it as

```
Read(None, Property(key, None))
```

Secondly you are creating actor with "PropertiesLookup_${self.path.name}" in name. But your log output shows that this actor name doesn't contain "PropertiesLookup" string.

In addition, notice that your path as logged includes a `$a` which suggests that an anonymous actor is in fact in the path, which isn't what's in your `actorSelection` call.

Comment: The Lookup actor does log, yes. I think the Lookup isn't mentioned in that log because it does a tell and passes the sender it's given in the apply method. I give it a unique name to avoid clashes.

Comment: I think, there might be also problem with 'Master' actor parent. I see from log `akka://NN/user/$a/Master` that Master is created by some anonymous actor. In your actor selection code you are assuming, that Master is created by `user` actor. So basically the path is just wrong.

Comment: Ahh yes. I'd seen that but wasn't sure, thought nothing of it. Presumably the `actorSelection` returns an actor of path "default/dead-letter" hence why no delivery. Thanks & Merry Christmas!

Comment: This helped! Now there's no `$a` as I moved the part that creates the Master actor to use `context.system`, which resolved the problem. Update your post with this info and I'll accept it as the answer. Thanks again!